# UnExpected reply from GCM Server when i am sending the Expected URL

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

**Question (i)****

I have registered my android app in my mobile (Samsung Galaxy Pop) i am recieved a

```
registrataion_id   
APA91bG9NI4U2jr4sUn1HLy5nHMFe1e0JOTgOoZv1Px**********************************
```

when i sent this registration_id to server side code which is refrenced from here
here i used function `SendNotification` having 2 parameters

1. My Registration_ID
2. My Message Which i want to show on notufication

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/434338/Android-GCM-Push-Notification

I hit the GCM- Server and the result I got is

```
id=0:1368258967353783%978fee9266d6cf16
```

I did not understand what does this response means ? is it good ? bad ?

**Question (ii)**

if mobile device gets registration id from gcm server is it registered or still waiting for server side to send the Registration ID to GCM Server

Please help !! , Thanks in advance

Comment: The id refers to ID generated by Google on this message you're sending. It is an indication of success, which of course means Google success in queueing your message to be sent, they will never guarantee you that the device is able to receive it. As for question 2, you can start sending notifications to device right after device gets their registration ID.

Comment: refer this url: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @ChorWaiChun Thanks for your response but i wanna know 1 thing i am hitting the server side manually by putting the Registration_id
How can i hit the the server through mobile device
1.Soap object ? or any other  method you would suggest

Comment: @Venkat Already done that but server side for them is PHP   , i want to do it in c# Thanks !!

Comment: Are you able to host any kind of server? A simple Http servlet (most people tend to call it Rest API nowadays) receiving simple parameters are enough for your server to capture the ID. Yes Soap can be an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to(i)**

The data you are getting is on plain text format and the data is refering to the message id. In this case the message was correctly sended.

To understand how it works visit this page [GCM Architectural Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#push-process)

**Answer to (ii)**

The way GCM works it's

- Your device request a registretion to GCM services.
- Device is registered correctly by receiving the regId.
- You send that regId to your server to receive push notifications.
- Server saves the data
- Servers wants to send a message to that device, sends a mesage using GCM services.
- The device, if it is online, receives it and knows wich app haves to start.
- The app receives the message.

On the same website you have further explanation, by the way start reading from getting started section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply But unfortunately my device is not notified with a push notification
1. i have registered google account on my phone 
2. My Android Application for pushnotification is running on the phone but did nt get push notification , Are these 2 are the major  key fields for the push notification in mobile
as far as reading is concerned i have done that already with some issues Thanks!

Comment: @AlexBcm How can i hit the server side through my mobile device
Soap object ? or any other method you would like to suggest

Comment: @Venkat i have sen that already thats why i am getting this id 
id=0:1368258967353783%978fee9266d6cf16 from gcm server  But i didnt get any message to my mobile

Comment: If you received the regID trough `GCMIntentService.onRegistered()`. Check the at `GCMIntentService.onMessage()` function, you have to implement the notification or what to do with the received message.